# semantic ui how to offset

Tags: semantic-ui

How can you offset columns in Semantic ui like you can in Bootstrap?

eg- in bootstrap a column with class "col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-2" is 5 column wide and skipping the first 2 column of the page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As offsets are not supported in Semantic UI's grid the only way I could think of working around this limitation is to insert an empty column where you need the offset:

```
<div class="one wide column"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. This way you have to right a little extra code but I found semantic's gridding system works better than bootstrap's.

Answer (score 2):

There is no predefined classes available for Offsetting Grids in Semantic UI.

https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/863

Answer (score 0):

within a Form.Group with e.g. 2 columns you can use

```
<Form.Group>
    <Form.Field inline width={8}/>
    <Form.Field>...(element which should have offset)...</Form.Field>
</Form.Group>
```